# ui-disable-choice with function

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

I am trying to disable options in a ui-select using a function in the ui-disable-choice. Calling a function doesn't seem to work. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

UI-Select

```
<ui-select 
            id="affSel--{{seat.sli_no}}"
            class="affSel"
            perf-no ="{{seat.perf_no}}"
            sli-no="{{seat.sli_no}}"
            ng-required="true"
            theme="bootstrap"
            on-select="changedAffiliate(mySeat.seat.sli_no, cartPerf.perf_no, seat.sli_no,seat)">

    <ui-select-match placeholder="-- Select person --">{{$select.selected.fname + ' ' + $select.selected.lname}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="affiliate in affiliates | seatAffTypeFilter:seat.seatAff" 
                        ui-disable-choice="checkDisable(affiliate.customer_no,cartPerf.perf_no, seat.sli_no)">
        <div ng-bind-html="affiliate.fname + ' ' + affiliate.lname"></div>
        <small ng-show="affiliate.disabled">{{AffSelected}}</small>
        <small ng-show="affiliate.validation_pass_age == 'N'">{{invalidAffLbl}}</small>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Function

```
$scope.checkDisable = function (customer_no, cur_perf_no, cur_sli_no) {
    $.each($scope.selectedAff, function (i) {
        if (this.customer_no == customer_no && this.perfNo == cur_perf_no && this.sli_no != cur_sli_no) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Check out "Single Object" dropdown in the link, I don't think `ui-dsiable-choice` takes function http://embed.plnkr.co/paSqp7/preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
$scope.checkDisable = function (customer_no, cur_perf_no, cur_sli_no) {
    return false; //true;
}
```

if this does not work it would mean that function types are not supported, but if it works, then you have code issue...

mostly you are not capturing result of `$.each` function, from the context it seems you need `_.find` rather than `$.each`

Comment: So return true; disabled all of my options so that seems to be the way to go. How would I use .find? Fairly new JQuery.

Comment: its not jquery `_.find` comes from `lodash` library which is another javascript library, if you find this answer useful please accept/upvote it

Comment: Your answer got me down the proper path. Thank you. This is what I ended up using.

Comment: `$scope.checkDisable = function (customer_no, cur_perf_no, cur_sli_no) {

        var result = $.grep($scope.selectedAff, function (e) {
            return e.customer_no == customer_no && e.perfNo == cur_perf_no && e.sli_no != cur_sli_no;
        });

        if (result.length == 1) {
            return true;
        } 
    }`

Comment: great.. glad it helped, i also learned something new `$.grep`, I do generally prefer `lodash` for such stuff